# #1# is not a symbol or lambda expression

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I try to create Euklid's algorithm in LISP. 
My code :

```
(defun euklid( x y)
   (cond
     ((= x y) x)
     ((> x y) (euklid((- x y) y)))
     )
```

I get an error `In the form (#1=(- X Y) Y), #1# is not a symbol or lambda expression.`
How I can correct this error ? I know that mistake is in my code.

Comment: You have extra parentheses around the arguments when calling `EUKLID`

Comment: @jkiiski, thx !

Comment: And you have the `*print-circle*` variable set to true (or else the debugger is doing that when preparing the error message). That's why the cryptic error message. If `*print-circle*` is `nil`, the error message would look like this "In the form ((- X Y) Y), (- X Y) is not a symbol or lambda expression". That's what it means. The `#1=` means "register the following object under the label 1", and then `#1#` means "refer to the object previously labeled as 1".  Through this "circle notation", Lisp supports the accurate rendering of cyclic structures an DAGs in print.

Comment: @Kaz great explanation, though I think "structure-sharing notation" (instead of "circle notation") is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4):

#### Reader variables

The `#1=...` syntax ([*sharpsign-equal*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/02_dho.htm)) means that your Lisp environment is binding whatever data is represented by `...` to the reader variable number 1. The `#1#` syntax ([*sharpsign-sharpsign*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/02_dhp.htm)) references the data that was previously bound to the same reader variable.

Thus, your Lisp environment is saying that the form `(- X Y)` is not a symbol or lambda expression, but does so by using a reader variable that points to the subexpression that is errorneous inside your function.

#### Not a symbol or lambda expression

Under normal evaluation rules (no special operator, no part of macro), a list like `(f x y ...)` is a function call where `f` is the function being called and `x`, `y`, ... are the arguments. The only possible values that can appear as `f` are symbols, like in `(mod 10 3)`, or literal lambda expressions, as in `((lambda (x y) (mod x y)) 10 3)`. If you need to determine at runtime which functions is being called, then use `funcall` (e.g. `(funcall (alexandria:compose #'/ #'+) 10 20)`).

Here you entered `(- X Y)`, which is neither a symbol nor a lambda expression.
You need to write instead:

```
(euklid (- X Y) Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function formula, you forgot one important fact that in your code the order of inputs is relevant.

This code makes the order of the input irrelevant:

```
;; correct version:

(defun euklid (x y)
  (let ((x (max x y))
        (y (min x y)))
    (cond
      ((= x y) x)
      ((> x y) (euklid (- x y) y)))))
```

First I corrected to:

```
(defun euklid (x y)
   (cond
     ((= x y) x)
     ((> x y) (euklid (- x y) y))))
```

But I realized that the order of the inputs is relevant with this function:

```
(euklid 3 9)
;; returns NIL!

(euklid 9 3)
;; returns 3
```

The `min` / `max` bindings to `y`, `x`, respectively makes the order of your input irrelevant and I think that is a behaviour what one wants from a function like `euklid`, isn't it?